# query mysql that return all records except contains 'Spanish copywriter'

Tags: sql, mysql

I´m trying to create query in mysql that return all my register from my table `'order'` except in column `order_name` has `'Spanish copywriter'`.

I try with:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` where order_name NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * from orders where order_name LIKE '%Spanish copywriter%')
```

this query return error.

Also i try with:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE order_name != 'Spanish copywriter' ORDER BY `orders`.`order_name` DESC
```

this query return, all register fom my db but return also data that it´s 'spanish copywriter'

Also i try with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE order_name <> 'Spanish copywriter'
```

I think that i need to do subquery to filter with like, but i don´t know how i can to build this query.

i share any example data:

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `publisher_id`, `client_id`, `order_number`, `order_name`, `order_date`, `sub_total`, `discount`, `discount_type`, `total`, `status`, `currency_id`, `show_shipping_address`, `redactor`, `external_order_id`, `note`, `internal_note`, `editor_note`, `client_note`, `reason_incidence`, `post_url`, `added_by`, `last_updated_by`, `billing_address`, `company_address_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(500, NULL, 29, '20429', 'Spanish Copywriter', '2024-01-29', 0, 0, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 0, 'no', '0', '0', '', NULL, '', '', '', NULL, 29, NULL, '0', 1, '2024-01-29 12:22:54', '2024-01-29 14:11:29'),
(501, NULL, 91, '20430', 'Brazilian Copywriter', '2024-01-29', 0, 0, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 0, 'no', '0', '0', '', NULL, '', '', '', NULL, 0, NULL, '', 1, '2024-01-29 12:41:30', '2024-02-05 07:26:34'),
(502, NULL, 29, '20431', 'Italian Copywriter', '2024-01-29', 0, 0, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 0, 'no', '5', '0', '', NULL, '', '', '', NULL, 29, NULL, '0', 1, '2024-01-29 15:45:07', '2024-01-30 14:07:41'),
(503, NULL, 91, '20432', 'Italian Copywriter', '2024-01-29', 0, 0, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 0, 'no', '5', '0', '', NULL, '0', '', '', NULL, 91, NULL, '', 1, '2024-01-29 15:49:26', '2024-01-30 14:13:27'),
(504, NULL, 29, '20433', 'English Copywriter', '2024-01-30', 0, 0, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 0, 'no', '4', '0', '', NULL, '', '', '', NULL, 29, NULL, '0', 1, '2024-01-30 05:50:06', '2024-02-01 10:02:34'),
(520, NULL, 35, '20449', '0', '2024-01-30', 0, 0, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 3, 'no', NULL, NULL, '', NULL, '', '', '', '0', 35, NULL, '0', 1, '2024-01-30 10:23:00', '2024-02-06 16:23:14'),
(521, NULL, 35, '20450', '0', '2024-01-30', 0, 10, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 0, 'no', '5', NULL, '', NULL, '0', '0', 1, '2024-01-30 10:32:35', '2024-02-28 13:59:52'),
```

Query should be return this data only:

```
(520, NULL, 35, '20449', '0', '2024-01-30', 0, 0, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 3, 'no', NULL, NULL, '', NULL, '', '', '', '0', 35, NULL, '0', 1, '2024-01-30 10:23:00', '2024-02-06 16:23:14'),
(521, NULL, 35, '20450', '0', '2024-01-30', 0, 10, 'percent', 0, 'publicada', 0, 'no', '5', NULL, '', NULL, '0', '0', 1, '2024-01-30 10:32:35', '2024-02-28 13:59:52'),
```

**SOLUTION**

If i use `not like` i have my result. I don´t know if exist `not like` operator

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE order_name NOT LIKE '%Spanish copywriter%'
```

Comment: Do you actually want `SELECT * from orders where order_name not LIKE '%Spanish copywriter%'`   ??

Comment: _"Query should be return this data only:"_ - why? The record with id 500 is the _only_ one that has `Spanish Copywriter` in the `order_name` column ...?

Comment: @KenLee yes, i will write my solition in this moment xD. thanks for your response and solution

Comment: @cbroe, yes in my db only have 10-12 record with this data

Comment: `where order_name NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from` how on earth could that ever make any sense?

Comment: _"yes in my db only have 10-12 record with this data"_ - but that doesn't match the sample data that you have shown then. When you go "this is my example data, and based on that I expect the following output" - then the two should actually _match_.

Comment: @cbroe yes, this 2 element should be show, but with my queries in my question, i can´t show it´because i was using like not, ```not like```

Comment: _"yes, this 2 element should be show"_ - but not according to what you have shown as sample data! Please _fix_ this, otherwise this question makes little sense to begin with.

Comment: Try ``SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE order_name NOT LIKE '%copywriter%'``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you,

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE order_name NOT LIKE '%copywriter%';
```

as suggested by ValNik a few minutes ago in a comment.

Comment: @ysth  ORDER is a reserved word. As in order by - where can I confirm your suggestion is required?

Comment: I only meant to code format the entire select. But in fact orders doesn't require backticks https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html